# Unable to access Python dictionary in a properties file from the main file

Tags: python

I have two Python scripts. One is a properties file with a dictionary of key-value pairs. The other is my main Python script where I import the first file so that I can access the values to use as variables in my database connection string.

The files are set up as follows:

config.py

```
db_config = {'DRIVER' : '{SQL SERVER}',
             'server' : 'myserver1',
             'database' : 'jira',
             'Trusted_Connection' : 'yes'}
```

main.py

```
import pyodbc
#properties file
import config

#Database setup
conStr = ('DRIVER=' + str(config.db_config['DRIVER']) +
          ';server=' + str(config.db_config['server']) +
          ';database=' + str(config.db_config['database']) +
          ';Trusted_Connection=' + 
str(config.db_config['Trusted_Connection']) + ';')
con = pyodbc.connect(conStr)
cur = con.cursor()
```

When I run this, I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\deidle\Python\misplacedFields.py", line 9, in <module>
    ';Trusted_Connection=' + str(config.db_config['Trusted_Connection']) + ';')
AttributeError: module 'config' has no attribute 'db_config'
```

It was working at one point and then I went to run it again and started getting the error. I tried changing the name of the dictionary and made sure I had correct spelling of everything in the main file. I have tried researching to see if there is anything else that I need to do in order to work with the config.py file, but all posts and articles I've read have the format that I have now. Both files are in the same folder in my directory so there shouldn't be any issues with accessing the files.

Comment: Did you try this?

from config import*

Comment: @ProjeshBhoumik: how would that help here? *Those names are not defined on the module they imported*.

Comment: You appear to have imported a different module with the same name. Debug this with `print(config.__file__)`.

Comment: are both in same folder, if yes, then try from config import db_config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're importing 'config' which is not your module because it already exists in your system by python , try to change your module name to something different

Comment: It would be better to first figure what module *is* being imported, as `config` is not in the standard library. Its another local module being pulled in from somewhere.